# How long do I need to mine until I see some coins in my wallet?

Tags: cpu-mining, pool-mining

I just started mining today and I set up my Address in the miner but I'm unsure if I did everything right and I'm mining "into" my wallet.

Mining with Claymore on I4700MQ with 6MB Cache on -t3 settings.

160 h/s

cryptomonero.com:1001

Wallet at MyMonero

It's a Notebook CPU but I got heat under control.
Once I know that my miner is set up correctly I will probably switch hardware.
It doesn't matter how much I receive, I just need some verification.

Follow up question: Do I have to let my miner run through "in one session" until I've hit a threshold or can I interrupt it and continue later without losing my progress which was under the threshold?

Answer (score 12):

The reason you haven't seen a payout is because most pools have a threshold level below which they won't bother sending xmr to you.

Your share per tick is: 160 H/s / 50.53e^6 H/s, with a network rate of 50 megahash per sec, right now.  The previous mining reward was 9.2481 and a tick happens every 2 minutes.

With a threshold of 0.1 XMR we get:

`0.1 XMR / [(160 H/s / 50.53e^6 H/s) * 9.2 XMR / tick * 0.5 tick / min] / 1440 min / day = 4.77 days`

In other words, if the pool has a threshold of 0.1 XMR before paying out you can expect to mine for almost two days without seeing any returns.  On top of that comes any variance.  Some small pools might not find a block the day you're due for a reward, which would cause an additional day in delays.

Follow up answer: No, you can interrupt, and come back to it later. Your balance shows the amount already won. Every time your balance changes, it's your fair share of the block reward, which the pool holds for you until you cross the payout treshold.

However, note that interruptions affect how much you will win in the first place. There are 2 different pool policies PPS (pay per share) and PPLNS (pay per last N shares).
With PPS, you will always win a piece of block reward proportional to your shares submitted to the pool / total shares submitted to the pool. With PPLNS it's a bit different, to discourage pool hopping.

Comment: There are only 1440 minutes per day, though.  Not 3600.  There are 3600 seconds per hour, so that's probably where you remembered that number from.

Comment: Thanks!  You're absolutely right, of course! I've edited the post to use the correct number of minutes in a day :)

Comment: @expez You said you've edited to use the correct number of minutes in a day, but your formula still contains "3600 min / day" ;)

Answer (score 4):

Based on current network hash rate and block reward:

```
days to get paid = threshold * network_hash_rate / (720 * block_reward * your_hash_rate)
                 = 0.1       * 50,000,000        / (720 * 9.1          * 160)
                 = 4.8
```

---

Here is a step by step explanation of how you can go about it:

```
network hash rate:         NHR  = 50 MH/s
blocks per day:            B    = 720
block reward:              Rew  = 9.1 XMR
```

Now you can calculate your solo mining **average** stats:

```
your hash rate:            HR   = 160 H/s
blocks you'll find daily:  BD   = B x HR / NHR = 0.00228
your average daily reward: DR   = BD x Rew = 0.021 XMR
days to find a block:      Days = 1 / BD = 438
```

And finally you can apply the pool details:

```
pool threshold:            T    = 0.1
average days to get paid:  Days = T / DR = 0.1 / 0.021 = 4.8 days
```

Comment: good explanation. The current network hash (NHR) is the one of the pool right?
[Example supportxmr](https://supportxmr.com) pool have 28.94 MH/s
instead of Network hashrate: 295.87 MH/s